# How to change directory of binlogs on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, binlog, mysqlbinlog

Current config:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/data/mysql
log-bin=test
```

Updated config:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/data/mysql
log-bin=/binlogdata/test
log-bin-index=/binlogdata/test.index
```

What I did was:

1. Stop mysql service
2. Update my.cnf
3. Move the current binlogs to destination path using:

```
mv /data/dir/test.* /binlogdata/
```

4. Update /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld I added /binlogdata/** rw
5. Reload apparmor
6. I excecuted chown on binlogdata

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /binlogdata
```

7. Start mysql service

Error on /var/log/mysql/error.log is

```
mysqld got signal 11 ;
```

Comment: show the full log from the startup.

Answer (score 0):

I already got it to work after I added the 3rd line.

[image]